# Android population listviews

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a very basic question about populating listviews in android.  Right now, if I wanna do so, I use a SimpleCursorAdapter and it works very well.  But since my Programm is getting more sophisticated I want manipulate the data, before it is displayed (You know, formating the Strings a.s.o.)  The problem I face is, that on the way from the database request to the ListElements, there is not really an point, where I can manipulate the data. Since I have four TextViews per ListElement, the ArrayAdapter is, as far as I know, not possible.  Since I am very new to Android I don't even know what to google for.

Thanks a lot for your help,
Daniel

Comment: I found that: [click here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) It should help you!

Comment: So you really have to write your own adapter?  I hoped there is an easier way, but I will try it and let you know, if it worked.  Thank you.

Comment: yeah... but it isn't very hard. really! You only have to overwrite the getView-method and... voilá!

Comment: @Sephy he has asked only 3 questions here and even you are telling him to accept answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way of doing so is in the `getView` of your adapter. You could do something like this :

```
class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ContactAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rowcontact, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.lastname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowTop);
                holder.firstname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowBottom);
                holder.iconContact = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconContact);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            String item = getItem(position);
            int i = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);

            switch (i) {
            ...
            }
            if (item != null) {
                holder.lastname.setText(item.split("-")[0]);
                holder.firstname.setText(item.split("-")[1]);
                holder.iconContact.setImageBitmap(bm);
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView lastname;
        TextView firstname;
        ImageView iconContact;
    }
}
```

You can find full code example [there](http://android-in-action.com/index.php?post/Droid-Contact-005%E2%80%93Set-up-and-customize-ListView-01). With the holder example, you can set up your 4 views and update them.